# Different behavior in local and on Github Actions for integration tests due to fixtures issue and typeorm

Tags: typescript, integration-testing, github-actions, typeorm

I can't pass the CI, all the test suites is passing fine on local.

Here is the problematic test:

`src/workout/repositories/workout.typeorm.repository.inte.ts`

```
  it('should find workout by program id', async () => {
    const workoutData = workoutDataBuilder({
      id: HardCodedValuesEnum.workoutId,
      title: 'Leg Workout',
    })
    const workout = new Workout(workoutData)
    const program = new Program(programFixture)
    program.workouts = [workout]
    await programRepository.save(program)
    const expectedWorkout = await workoutRepository.save(workout)

    const [receivedWorkout] = await workoutRepository.findByProgramId(
      HardCodedValuesEnum.programId,
    )

    expect(receivedWorkout.id).toStrictEqual(expectedWorkout.id)
  })
```

Here is the basic implementation:

`src/workout/repositories/workout.typeorm.repository.ts`

```
@EntityRepository(Workout)
export class TypeOrmWorkoutRepository
  extends Repository<Workout>
  implements WorkoutRepository
{
  findByProgramId(programId: string): Promise<Workout[]> {
    const workout = this.find({
      relations: ['program'],
      where: {
        program: {
          id: programId,
        },
      },
    })

    return Promise.resolve(workout)
  }
}
```

and here is my Github actions workflow:

```
name: Tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:

  backend-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: back
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'yarn'
        cache-dependency-path: '**/back/yarn.lock'
    - run: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
    - run: mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE corposano' -uroot -proot
    - run: mysql -e 'ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ""' -uroot -proot
    - run: yarn
    - run: yarn build
    - run: yarn jest
    - run: yarn test:inte
    - run: yarn test:e2e
```

As I can't reproduce the issue on my computer, I can't pass that error coming from Github Actions:

```
Run yarn test:inte
yarn run v1.22.19
$ jest --testTimeout=10000 -c jest-inte.json --runInBand --forceExit
FAIL src/workout/repositories/workout.typeorm.repository.inte.ts (10.821 s)
  ● TypeOrm Workout Repository › should find workout by program id
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
      158 |     )
      159 |
    > 160 |     expect(receivedWorkout.id).toStrictEqual(expectedWorkout.id)
          |                            ^
      161 |   })
      162 |
      163 |   it.each([
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/workout/repositories/workout.typeorm.repository.inte.ts:160:28)
PASS src/athlete/repositories/typeorm-athlete.repository.inte.ts
PASS src/exercise/repositories/type-orm-exercise.repository.inte.ts
PASS src/program/repositories/type-orm-program.repository.inte.ts
PASS src/daily-task/repositories/daily-task.typeorm.repository.inte.ts
PASS src/exercise/repositories/type-orm-exercise-template.repository.inte.ts
Test Suites: 1 failed, 5 passed, 6 total
Tests:       1 failed, 22 passed, 23 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        20.43 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Am out of ideas to get clues and debug. How can I debug on the CI and understand what's happening there differently?

Comment: You use `${{ matrix.node-version }}`, but you don't specify what version to use anywhere; there is no `strategy` instruction. Have a look at https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ for pointers like that.

Comment: Might be useful, but over the 100+ tests I've written so far on this project, only this one is problematic. Therefore I doubt that the node version is the issue here.